# Can I use symbolic links in Dokuwiki's page files?

Tags: dokuwiki

I'm planning to try using dokuwiki to manage my large collection of notes, and one of the major attractions is its flat file basis that'll allow me to edit via scripts etc. I had a question - suppose a page's material fits into multiple namespaces. If I were to create the file in one namespace and then create symlinks in the other namespace directories, would that work? Or would that screw up revisions etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. But yes, this will mess with your revisions a bit:

- when DokuWiki saves a page, it copies the data of the old page to the attic
- the name of the attic file is the same as the page that was edited, but with a timestamp appended
- because new attic files are created you can't work with symlinks in the attic

Imagine you have the following setup:

```
data/pages/original.txt
data/pages/copy.txt -> original.txt
```

You now can edit the pages `original` and `copy` in your wiki and they will both always be the same. However old revisions of the pages will be split between the two, depending on which page you edited.

Comment: Thanks! Suppose I use the same pagename but in different namespaces: e.g. data/topic1/page.txt and data/topic2/page.txt (where the latter is a symlink to the former)? Would that address the revisions issue as well?

Comment: that's exactly the same. You could symlink the namespaces (directories) though. You would need to create the symlinks in the attic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with file level consider

- [Include](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:include) plugin to share content between pages.
- Creation of some 'commons' namespace for such pages to be DRY.
- [Namespace templates](https://www.dokuwiki.org/namespace_templates) (+ additional [plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:templatepagename)).
- Pulling content from page side instead of pushing it to pages. [This](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:datatemplate) might be good to start with. You can always include some php code or even write your own plugin.